# How to create publishing profile for azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure, publishing

How to create publishing profile for a website running on azure virtual machine?

I know how to do it for Azure Web Site, but can this be done if I have IIS running on a VM in azure?

I also have a console application running using task scheduler on this VM, it would be nice to automate that deployment too.

( After working with Rails and Php frameworks, I miss the common config file used by the website and CronJob to connect to the DB)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to set up Webdeploy in the azure VM. it is same as an on-premises server.

[Web Deploy Installation.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569059%28v=WS.10%29.aspx). You need to install prerequisites - .net framework.

[Configuring IIS 7 with webdeploy](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy) / [Or with IIS8](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later)

[Set up endpoints on azure vm to do webdeploy.](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-set-up-endpoints/) Port 8172 for Webdeploy.

Then you can create a publish profile in Visual Studio 2012/13 to deploy to this endpoint.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx

or You can do it using Powershell scripts.
sample-
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Deploy-a-Web-App-to-Two-99f1a3bc